# How to programmatically set a ListView item/row height?

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to set the row height of a listView item programmatically in the Processing language (a java wrapper for art work) 
In the code below I tried to do that with the commented lines. But it gives the error;
Any idea?

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from ViewGroup.LayoutParams to
>   AbsListView.LayoutParams

```
ListView self;

  public void init() {
    setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    setAlpha(255);
    self = this;
    layout = new RelativeLayout(parent.getActivity());
    if (title != "") {
      TextView tv = new TextView(parent.getActivity());
      tv.setText(title);
      setHeaderDividersEnabled(true);
      addHeaderView(tv);
    }
    setAdapter(adapter);
    setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p, View view, int position, long id) {
        selection = adapter.getItem(int(id)).toString();
        layout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        try {
          parentCallback.invoke(parent, new Object[] { self });
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        self.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((ViewManager) self.getParent()).removeView(self);
        parent.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            layout.removeAllViews();
            layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }
        }
        );
      }
    }
    );
    try {
      parentCallback = parent.getClass().getMethod("onSelectionKListSelection", new Class[] { SelectionKList.class });
      PApplet.println("Found onSelectionKListSelection...");
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    }
    parent.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void run() {
        parent.getActivity().addContentView(self, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) self.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(150, 150, 150, 150);
        self.setDividerHeight(5);

     //    LayoutParams params = self.getLayoutParams(); // Set the height of the Item Vie
     //    params.height = 40; 
     //    self.setLayoutParams(params);
      }
    }
    );
  }
```

Comment: You are casting the LayoutParams to a wrong type of Layout params.. change the Object type to the type suggested in the error: `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` and not `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`, I think the later is the LayoutParams of `RelativeLayout`...

Comment: Welcome to SO. It will help if you make your code a [mcve].

Comment: I changed the the code the way you suggested, but il still gives the same error.